# Book referring to software where you provide facts and the conclusion you want to reach

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm not sure if this is sci-fi, might be more humour (my mind keeps connecting it to *Hitchhiker's Guide*, so maybe same author/style, but really not sure about that).

Anyway, the key part I'm trying to find is someone writes software where, you enter the facts and the problem you are trying to solve, and the software uses the facts to produce the logical solution. This initial version doesn't sell at all.

So they rewrite the software so that you give it the facts AND the conclusion you want to reach, and the software produces the arguments that gets you there (whether logical or not).

I think there was a crack about the army and navy using it, but different versions..?

This was probably not a key part of the story (maybe only a page or two in the entire book), but it's the part I remember and liked the most.

Update: I read this at least 10 years ago, but it probably wasn't new even then.

Comment: The book involves aliens, time travel, and electric monks, so it definitely counts as science fiction.

Comment: Honorable mention for _[The Stochastic Man](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1408115.The_Stochastic_Man)_ by Robert Silverberg.

Comment: Nice, he solved [Hilbert's Entscheidungsproblem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsproblem)

Comment: There is also the Guide 2.0 in Mostly Harmless which bends reality to meet the wants and needs of the owner.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is surely "[Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?2107)" a novel (and later  TV series) by Douglas Adams - which explains the connection to the HHGTTG in your mind.

The program was written by Gordon Way:

> Gordon’s great insight was to design a program which allowed you to
> specify in advance what decision you wished it to reach, and only then
> to give it all the facts. The program’s task, which it was able to
> accomplish with consummate ease, was simply to construct a plausible
> series of logical-sounding steps to connect the premises with the
> conclusion.
>
> ‘And I have to say that it worked brilliantly. Gordon was able to buy
> himself a Porsche almost immediately despite being completely broke
> and a hopeless driver. Even his bank manager was unable to find fault
> with his reasoning. Even when Gordon wrote it off three weeks later.’
>
> ‘Heavens. And did the program sell very well?’
>
> ‘No. We never sold a single copy.’
>
> ‘You astonish me. It sounds like a real winner to me.’
>
> ‘It was,’ said Richard hesitantly. ‘The entire project was bought up,
> lock, stock and barrel, by the Pentagon. The deal put WayForward on a
> very sound financial foundation.

There was indeed a crack about different services using different versions. By analysing Pentagon policies, it was apparent that the US Navy was using version 2.00, while for unknown reasons the Air Force was using the beta version of 1.5.

Comment: I had a feeling it was Dirk Gently, but couldn't find the relevant passage! Good job on that speed.

Comment: That was amazingly fast. I tried Google, and failed utterly. How did you find this?

Comment: It was a favorite part of the book for me too. I immediately remembered the book and that the Pentagon bought the program, then it was just a matter of finding the right page. Nice to see human memory can still beat google (under some conditions)!

Comment: It's embarrassing to realize how long it's been since I refreshed my memory of that book. I remember the general plot, but I didn't recall this bit about the software at all.

Comment: It was also make into Episode 1 of the Dirk Gently TV series. (Not to be confused with the Dirk Gently's Holistic Detective Agency TV series).

Comment: @Acccumulation There were TWO Dirk Gently TV series?!

Comment: @Lorendiac Same here. And it's one of my favourite books too!

Comment: Sounds like the program's gone into general use by the government and no longer limited to just the military.

Comment: Well so technically they did sell a single copy.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica First, there was a one-season BBC series that had great interpretations of the characters but weak plotting. It was an episodic comedy procedural like Monk or Psych. The other was a two-season BBC America series that was exactly the opposite. It had quirky, complicated season-length plots, but the characters were almost entirely unrecognizable. Overall I _slightly_ preferred the second.

Comment: @o0'. If you want to get technical, they sold the original. They never produced a copy to sell.

Comment: @AJM-Reinstate-Monica Yes, and the BBC America one is available on YouTube.